# How to generate a net on a 8-dimensional sphere

Tags: matlab, random, geometry

Using Matlab, how to generate a net of 3^10 points that are evenly located (or distributed) on the 8-dimensional unit sphere?

Comment: I think this question is more about programming and algorithm.

Comment: I'm reading the answers up to this point and I feel that they miss the real point of the question.  I don't think we're after 3^10 points that follow a random distribution, but rather, 3^10 points that are equidistant from their neighbors, like the 20 verticies of a dodecahedron would distribute on a unit sphere if the center were 1 unit from each of the vertices in question.  In other words, we're after an 8-dimensional regular polyhedron.  Is that correct?

Comment: For the record, thinking about an 8-dimensional sphere is making my nose bleed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from wikipedia [n-sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere)

> To generate uniformly distributed
>   random points on the (n − 1)-sphere
>   (i.e., the surface of the n-ball),
>   Marsaglia (1972) gives the following
>   algorithm.
>
> Generate an n-dimensional vector of
>   normal deviates (it suffices to use
>   N(0, 1), although in fact the choice
>   of the variance is arbitrary),
>   \mathbf{x}=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n).
>
> Now calculate the "radius" of this
>   point,
>   r=\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2}.
>
> The vector \frac{1}{r} \mathbf{x} is
>   uniformly distributed over the surface
>   of the unit n-ball.

A matlab code fragment that accomplishes this is:

```
numdims = 8;
numpts = 3^10;
x = randn([numdims numpts]);
lx = repmat(sqrt(sum(x.^2,1)), [numdims 1]);
x = x./lx;
%x(:,j) is the jth point on the circle)
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple way to get points on the n-d unit sphere is to create an n-d cube, cut away the corners, and normalize the remaining radii to 1. Note that without the cutting, the distribution won't be uniform.

However, since the volume of the hypersphere relative to the enclosing box decreases as the dimensionality goes up, this is not a particularly efficient way.

A better way is to generate an array of n-d normally distributed points (radii), and to normalize them to the radius of the sphere - the n-d normal distribution is radially symmetric, and thus the distribution on the surface will be uniform

```
%# set-up
nPoints = 3^10;
nDim = 8;

%# create normally distributed variables
points = randn(nPoints,nDim);

%# normalize by dividing by the norm (=square root of sum(points.^2,2) )
points = bsxfun(@rdivide,points,sqrt(sum(points.^2,2)));
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere) we read that

*an n-sphere of radius r is defined as the set of points in (n + 1)-dimensional Euclidean space which are at distance r from a central point, where the radius r may be any positive real number*

so your problem becomes one of generating 3^10 vectors in 7-space.  Without losing anything we can let `r = 1`.  The approach will be to generate random vectors in 7-space and then normalise them to unit length in the usual way

Here's some code I knocked up in a hurry, I know I should have vectorised things and not written loops, I'll leave that to OP.  The code shouldn't need any explanation.

```
pointset = rand(3^10,7);
normset = zeros(3^10,1);
for ix = 1:3^10
  normset(ix) = norm(pointset(ix,:));
end
for ix = 1:3^10
  pointset(ix,:) = pointset(ix,:)/normset(ix);
end
```

This relies, of course, on Matlab's PRNG produding uniformly distributed numbers to create a uniformly distributed net on the 8-sphere.

Comment: I think that to get a uniform distribution on the surface, you would need to replace rand with randn (the values need to be gaussian distributed, not uniformly distributed).  
I'm sure that if you use rand, you at least need to subtract off 1/2, otherwise all your points will be in the first hyperquadrant (x_j > 0 for all x,j).